# Most restrictive iptables outgoing HTTP/HTTPS traffic rule

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm trying to make the least permissive outgoing TCP HTTP/HTTPS connection in iptables. So far I have:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I am assuming new is needed for client-intiated ssl handshakes, if my goal was to make outgoing web traffic as restrictive as possible, is there anything else in the rule you folks would recommend?

Thank you very much

Comment: Which role the computer running IPTables has? Is it a HTTP/HTTPS client or server? Your rule is fine for a server, but your words "least permissive outgoing" is contradictory to the server role.

Answer (score 2):

Your `iptables` rule is sufficient, provided you also have:

```
# Permit replies to existing (e.g. inbound) connections
iptables -A OUTPUT -j RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Reject all other output traffic
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

REJECT is better than DROP in the OUTPUT chain to speed up failures.

However I'm not sure what are you trying to prevent / protect from? It's very easy to run *any service* on port 80 or 443. For example botnets, or even VPN or SSH servers will happily run on these ports and if someone takes over your server you won't stop him from connecting to their services by restricting outgoing traffic only to ports 80 and 443.

You may be better served with a *HTTP proxy with a whitelist* of permitted URLs or at least a whitelist of IPs in your `iptables -A OUTPUT` chain (can be conveniently done through `ipset`).

Restricting only the output ports will probably not do what you want.

Comment: the goal is to prevent, to the greatest extent, data exfil on my network, and what you pointed out about using traditional web ports to do such makes sense. Note that I made a naive assumption that browsers would always request locally from 80/443, but I'm assuming that's not the case as I start inspecting traffic. A proxy would be a good solution, but I would prefer to run the proxy outside the network and its not in the cards at the moment. Will the non-allowance of 'NEW' output effect outgoing HTTP/S requests?

Comment: @Rice - if you want to stop client browsers from directly accessing the web you must prevent direct traffic from clients to Internet and only permit traffic to your web Proxy. The proxy should sit in a different network segment (sometimes called DMZ) that has access both inside and outside. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite your rules as follows:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Here is a summary of what these rules mean:

- The first rule allow all related traffic (replies to initiated
- The second rule allow HTTP/HTTPS traffic.
- The last rule is needed to drop all other remaining traffic.

You need to be careful about two things:

1. You need to make sure you allow other types of traffic whenever needed.
2. These rules are added to `OUTPUT` chain which means they will applied to traffic originated from the same machine. If this machine is acting as router/firewall, you need to add these rules to `FORWARD` chain.
3. You may need to consider adding rules to other chains like `INPUT`. This depends on your setup and requirements.

Comment: I'm thinking twice about my decision to allow 'NEW', is it actually necessary? For example I have no idea which ports my HTTP/S traffic will be headed out of locally and therefore I should always ACCEPT NEW for arbitrary outgoing port ranges? Seems like it could lead to potential for data exfiltration